# EFS locked me out all on its own?

Tags: windows-7, efs

I have a handful of files that are encrypted on disk.  I am unable to access them or remove the encryption.  I was able to access these files somewhat recently, as I can see when I copied some of them to another drive 2 months ago.  The files are not listed in my Backblaze account, so they must have been inaccessible for 30 days or so.

I don't actually intend to use EFS, but I've noticed that sometimes when I extract files from ZIP files, they are encrypted when written to disk.  (This whole time, I thought the green file names listed in Windows Explorer were for some on-disk compression or something.)

In the certmgr, I have one personal certificate and it appears to have been issued 3 days ago.  Is it normal for the certificate to be automatically re-generated like this?

[image: Certificate]

My questions:

- **What (probably) happened to make these files inaccessible?**  (I've changed nothing, installed nothing, have looked for CyrptoLocker viruses and similar, no issues.)
- **Is there anything I can do to get the files back?**